# file_get_contents and file_put_contents with large files

Tags: php, regex, file-io

I'm trying to get file contents, replace some parts of it using regular expressions and preg_replace and save it to another file:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.txt', true);

$content_replaced = preg_replace('/\[\/m\]{1}\s+(\{\{.*\}\})\s+[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u', 'replaced text', $contents);


if ($content_replaced) {
  file_put_contents('file_new.txt', $content_replaced);
  echo "Successful!";
}
else {
  echo "Some error ocurred";
}
```

this piece of code works fine with small files, but when I try the original file, which is about 60Mb, it just keeps giving me a message "Some error ocurred".

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Update. No errors in the logs, memory limit is set to 1024M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're hitting some regex limit. Heck, some time ago I hit a limit [with 1000 chars](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=11649)... with 60Mb of input I bet you will likely hit regex limits everywhere also with really simple patterns. I will try at least to simplify it as much as possible, making it ungreedy with `.*?` instead of `.*` if possible.

To get more information, just check the return value of [`preg_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php).

Comment: The problem was - PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR. My files (the small and the large one) had different encodings. Thanks for pointing me to the right track.

Comment: You're welcome. But, just for curiosity, after correcting the encoding issue, are you able to parse a 60Mb file with the above regex?

Answer (score 4):

I've had max/limit issues with `file_put_contents`.

No idea what the limits might be, but using `fwrite` solved my troubles and I put down the bottle.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably running out of memory.  What's the memory_limit set to? (phpinfo() will tell you).  You may be able to increase the memory limit like:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```