# How to limit the speed of file_put_contents in php?

Tags: php, download

I have the following php code for downloading web files directly to my web server:

```
function fileDownload()

{

    $url = $_POST['downloadlink'];

    $filename = $_POST['filename'];

    $dir = "downloads/";

    $filepath = $dir . $filename;

    file_put_contents($filepath, fopen($url, 'r'));

}
```

The above php function works well for downloading files less than 128 mb but, when file size exceeds 128 mb then a heavy traffic load is created on my server for which my server becomes temporarily unavailable and aborts all connections. So, my file download is aborted. I was thinking if there is any way to limit the rate of  `file_put_contents` function so that my server work well even when I am downloading a file that is greater than 128 mb.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603281/file-get-contents-and-file-put-contents-with-large-files

Comment: The above link doesn't give the solution of how to limit the speed of `file_put_contents` function....

Comment: I know, but maybe the reason why your server goes down...

Comment: What memory limits do you have in your php.ini?

Comment: It is not the issue of memory limit but the issue of creating massive traffic load on my server for which my server goes offline when I want to download big files.....My server can't handle that much of traffic at a time so I want to limit the speed so that my server work smoothly....

Comment: http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/download-speed-limit-and-throttling-for-apache-2-4

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [stream filter](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.filters.php) which could limit the rate with e.g. a [token bucket](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket). I did all that for you: [bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle)

But you can register that filter only on streams (i.e. file handles). In case of `file_put_contents()` it must be registered to the input stream:

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$in = fopen($url, 'r');

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();
$throttle->setRate(100, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // 100KiB/s
$throttle->throttle($in);

file_put_contents($filepath, $in);
```

If you want to throttle an output stream you have to use a method which writes on streams e.g. `stream_copy_to_stream()`:

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$in  = fopen($url, 'r');
$out = fopen($filepath, 'w');

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();
$throttle->setRate(100, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // 100KiB/s
$throttle->throttle($out);

stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out);
```

Effectively there's no big difference between both solutions. Both will read and write with 100KiB/s. You might want to adjust `max_execution_time` for that script.

---

BTW. Don't use `$_POST` for your stream sources.