# File size in fileputcontens

Tags: php

When I use `file_put_contents` and want put long string with 5Mb info to file, it create me 1Mb file, cut a first 1M of string. Why? What I need to do to write all 5 Mb to file?

Comment: Share the code you are currently using with us so we can help you

Comment: $string - is a some string with 5660652 symbols.

Comment: file_put_contents($path,$string); - create a file with 1048576 symbols (first symbols of string)

Comment: You might want to look at [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) instead of `file_put_contents()` as [it has a buffer limit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10921463/5663450) i.e; `fwrite($file, $string);`

Comment: I tryed it too, no result

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark a bit here, upload all of your source code if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What about your post_max_size value in your php.ini? It should be greater than 1M.

2) If you are storing data in a for(each) loop, you should use file_put_contents($in_file, $data, **FILE_APPEND**) flag, otherwise the file is overwritten in each pass of the loop and its content is only last value of stored variable.

Comment: $sting = "aaa..."; more than 5000000 times
file_put_contents($path,$string); - create a file with 1048576 symbols (first symbols of string)

Comment: What is the size of $string? Are you using some loop to store $string content to the $path file?

Comment: No, string is given from database. It has 5 million characters, approx size 5 mb. but in file function write only 1024 kb

Comment: So you make one select from DB that returns aprox. 5MB of data to $string and then you file_put_contents that string to $file? No loop?

Comment: No, I make more than 20 selects. First 10 selects is less than 1Mb

Comment: Can you, please, post your code here? At least how you select from DB and store to file?

Comment: foreach( $input as $key=>$value )
 {
  
  file_put_contents($IN_FILE,$input[$key]->test);
/*...*/
}